# Is reportportal integration is possible in karate 0.9.5version

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform, reportportal

In my project we are using report portal, But I want to integrate in karate framework version 0.9.5, Is it possible to integrate. Please guide me steps to follow.

Comment: @Peter Thomas
Accepted previous answer